# Reduce the program size(bytes)

Tags: python

```
import os
os.system('ffmpeg -i aa.wmv -map 0:1 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -strict experimental -cutoff 22000 m.aac')
os.system('ffmpeg -i aa.wmv -c:v libx264 -an my.mp4')
os.system('ffmpeg -i m.aac -i my.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc myq.mp4')
```

Is there a way to reduce this program's size in python.This file is of 292 bytes.I want a program that consumes less memory.

Comment: `292 bytes` is consuming too much memory??!! Also, if all your program does is make system calls, then why not just write a `bash` script?

Comment: Do you want toe file to need less file storage or do you want the processes to use less RAM?

Comment: This *is* smaller than the 292 bytes you find too much. It's only 247 bytes. Also, notably, any file larger than 0 bytes consumes disk space in *pages*, where a single page typically is 4096 Kb. What is your reason to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

147 bytes:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -i aa.wmv -map 0:1 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -strict experimental -cutoff 22000 m.aac
ffmpeg -i aa.wmv -c:v libx264 -an my.mp4
ffmpeg -i m.aac -i my.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc myq.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can gzip (or use any other compression method) and decompress when needed.

Comment: I tried this and the result of gziped version is 172 bytes.

Comment: @GüntherJena Of the original python version or your shorter version? Actually I get 214 bytes for your file and 151 when gzipping yours.

Comment: I tried with the original code. Copy/Paste might lack of copying line endings correctly. Original file has 251 bytes and gzip 172 bytes.